# The argument passed to findOne must be an options object, use findById if you wish to pass a single primary key value I have done this in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

These are mine routes for getting and when i am trying to process with it i am getting an error Error The argument passed to findOne must be an options object, use findById if you wish to pass a single primary key value.

```
  var express = require('express');
        var router = express.Router();
        var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
        var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
        var models=require('../models');
        var mkdirp=require('mkdirp');
        var fs=require('fs-extra');
        var resizeImg=require('resize-img');


          // Get Product model
        var Product = require('../models/product');

            // Get Product model
            var Category = require('../models/category');

                /*
                * Get products index 
                */

                router.get('/',function(req,res){

                    var count;

                    models.Product.count(function(c){
                        count=c;
                    })
                   models.Product.find(function(err,products){
                    res.render('admin/products',{
                        products:products,
                        count:count
                    });
                   });
                });
```

**This is my Get method for getting products**

```
                    /*
                    * GET add product
                    */
        router.get('/add-product', function (req, res) {

            var title = "";
            var desc = "";
            var price = "";

            models.Category.find(function (err, categories) {
                res.render('admin/add_product', {
                    title: title,
                    desc: desc,
                    categories: categories,
                    price: price
                });
            });


        });

        module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find method expects first parameter to be an object containing filters. Try it like this:

```
        models.Category.find({}, function (err, categories) {
            res.render('admin/add_product', {
                title: title,
                desc: desc,
                categories: categories,
                price: price
            });
        });
```

Comment: I have tried like this in both methods its not giving me any errors and the
Executing (default): SELECT count(*) AS `count` FROM `Products` AS `Product`;
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `title`, `slug`, `desc`, `category`, `price`, `images`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Products` AS `Product` LIMIT 1;
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...

But Reloading and not going to any Page  and no errors

Comment: What happens when going on page ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error today. got it fixed as well. It came down to this. You have two functions.

Function1(expecting options object)

Function2(expecting a single key value)

If you call Function1, with a single key value, obviously, thats a type mismatch, in a way. Of course, this seems to be something which was the norm in the old days (I assume). So, the standard error returns, saying that, you are sending a single value when you should be sending an options object.

This is (in a way) similar to sending an int to a function, that is expecting a string.

So, there are two solutions here.

Solution 1 - use the alternate function that is already being suggested. Thats it, problem solved. (this depends on your situation, and the code you have written and libraries you are using).

Solution 2 - give what the Function1 is expecting. That would be, an options object.

In my case, I decided to call Function 1, with an options object. The code looked something like this.

```
const user = await SQUser.findOne({ where: { username: username } });
```

here, to be very specific, is the object, I am sending.

```
{ where: { username: username } }
```

That's it. problem solved. On a more personal note, it is better to stick to sending options object, as that is always a better implementation in most packages that you encounter during development.